# ASP Razor have button show/hide a label

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have page where a bunch of rows are being generated. Each Row has a button. On click of that button i want to show a label next to it with some text.

Below code has the label that i want to show. Now i need to update the code so that it only shows when the button is clicked. Please note that each button should only show its associated label.

```
<div class="row product-item">
<div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-right:0px;"><img src="~/Content/images/@p.image" style="width:100%;" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <p style="margin-bottom:2px;">@p.title</p>
    <p style="margin-top:2px;color:#868686;">@p.desc</p>

    <div style="padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;">
        <button style="float:left;margin-right:10px;" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Order</button>
        <p id="successlabel" style="color:#339966; float:left; margin-top:2px; display:none;">✔ Your selection has been added to your order!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jquery, this is one of many solutions:

```
    $(function () {
        $('button.btn-primary').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text() == 'Add to Order';
        }).click(function (e) {
            $(this).next().show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: will this show the buttons label or the <p> that has the id="successlabel"? i Want to toggle the <p>

Comment: in your html markups, `next()` of the `button` is the `p` element, @codeNinja